# sum column with duplicates in another table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Wrong Result
So i have two tables

1. Order
2. Staging

Order Table having column structure

```
+-------+---------+-------------+---------------+----------+
|  PO   | cashAmt | ClaimNumber | TransactionID | Supplier |
+-------+---------+-------------+---------------+----------+
| 12345 |     100 |       99876 | abc123        |     0101 |
| 12346 |      50 |       99875 | abc123        |     0102 |
| 12345 |     100 |       99876 | abc123        |     0101 |
+-------+---------+-------------+---------------+----------+
```

Staging Table having column structure

```
+----------+------------+-------------+---------------+
| PONumber | paymentAmt | ClaimNumber | TransactionID |
+----------+------------+-------------+---------------+
|    12345 |        100 |       99876 | abc123        |
|    12346 |         50 |       99875 | abc123        |
+----------+------------+-------------+---------------+
```

The query i am executing is

```
select sum(cashAmt) CheckAmount, count(ClaimNumber) TotalLines
FROM [order]  with (nolock)
WHERE TransactionID='abc123'
union
select sum(paymentAmt) CheckAmount, count(ClaimNumber) TotalLines
from Staging with (nolock)
where TransactionID='abc123'
```

but the sum is getting messed up because there is duplicate in one of the tables.

How can i edit that i get only uniques from the order table and the sums are correct

Comment: Select from a derived table where you use any of the myriad methods already posted on the site to eliminate duplicates from the results.

Comment: Are you ok with missing and/or duplicate rows at random times with these queries? Since this looks like a financial application I have a feeling you will likely say that isn't ok. You should consider not littering your database with NOLOCK. It is FAR more than just the occasional dirty read. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: if the sums match you only want one record, if they dont you want 2?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming duplicates in your table are OK.

Not sure why you are using no lock, it seems like it shouldn't be included.

You could use a table variable to store the distinct values.  You'll need to adjust the data types in the table variable to match your table structure.

I haven't tested the code below but it should look something like this.

```
DECLARE @OrderTmp TABLE (
  cashAmt MyNumericColumn numeric(10,2)
  , ClaimNumber int
  , TransactionID Int
)
INSERT INTO @OrderTmp
select Distinct 
    cashAmt
    ,ClaimNumber
    ,TransactionID 
FROM 
    [order] 
WHERE TransactionID='abc123'

SELECT DISTINCT 
select sum(cashAmt) CheckAmount, count(ClaimNumber) TotalLines
FROM @OrderTmp 
where TransactionID='abc123'
union
select sum(paymentAmt) CheckAmount, count(ClaimNumber) TotalLines
from Staging
where TransactionID='abc123'
```

Answer (score 0):

First ask yourself why are there duplicates in the Orders table?  There must be a reason why they are there.  I would deal with that first.

That issue aside, if the duplicates in the Orders table have a purpose and yet are not to be considered for this particular query, then you should be able to leave out the duplicates by simply changing the query to use `DISTINCT` on whatever field in the Orders table can reliably identify a duplicate.

`select Distinct fieldname sum(cashAmt)...` etc.